# exporting Interconnect VLAN to another GCP account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, colocation

I have my on-prem infrastructure at a co-lo site. The GCP interconnect was ordered through account1, but the VPC and cloud infrastructure belongs to account2. Is there a way I can connect the VPC in account2 to my on-prem using the interconnect in account1?

I am able to do something similar in both AWS and Azure, where they allow you to "export" the VIF or circuit from an owner account to another account that contains the cloud infrastructure.

I am relatively new to GCP so any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about a Dedicated Interconnect or a Partner Interconnect as possibilities might differ depending on the type of Interconnect ?

It also depends if account1 and account2 both belong to the same organisation.
Organisations are explained at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc).

You can use the same dedicated interconnect in different projects as long as the projects are in the same organisation by creating VLAN attachments in each project. A VLAN attachment attaches an Interconnect ot one VPC network.

If it is the case, for a given Interconnect there is currently a limit of 16 attachments globally and a quota of around 5 regional Vlan attachments.

You will find information on this on GCP public documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/dedicated/using-interconnects-other-projects).

If the accounts/projects are part of different organistations, then you could create a shared VPC that would share a VPC connected to the Interconnect link with other service projects that are part of a different organisation.
Shared VPC concept is explained at this [link](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc).
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am talking about a Dedicated Interconnect in this deployment. Account1 is owned by my organization, and account2 is owned by our customer. We are trying to attach the customer's VPC to our on-prem equipment using a Dedicated Interconnect owned by our organization. Like you mentioned, an Interconnect VLAN cannot be shared between different organizations, so this will not work in our case. I am exploring the "shared" VPC option based on your suggestion, but I think it will not work. Is there another way I can get my customer to connect their VPC to our on-prem equip

Comment: My mistake, Shared VPC connects only projects that are in the same organisation. Dedicated Interconnect can only be shared within an organisation. The only option I see then would be to use cloud VPN to connect your customer's VPC to your on premise network.